# Busca de duas colunas no banco de dados

Tags: php, sql, banco-de-dados, pdo, algoritmo-de-busca

Preciso de ajuda de como fazer uma busca em duas colunas, sou iniciante.

Se eu digito uma categoria ele acha, se eu digito uma cidade ele acha, porem, se eu digitar categoria e cidade ex: *agencias são paulo*  ele não retorna nada. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Estou utilizando PDO

```
<?php
include("conexao.php");

$pesquisa = $_POST["pesquisa"];


$cidades = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM edicao WHERE categoria LIKE ? OR cidade LIKE ? ");
$cidades->bindValue(1, "%" . $pesquisa . "%");
$cidades->bindValue(2, "%" . $pesquisa . "%");
$cidades->execute();

$resultado = $cidades->fetchAll();

if (!empty($pesquisa)) {


    foreach ($resultado as $uf_s) {
        ?>
        <div class="row" style="text-align: center;">
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            <div class="col-md-5" style=" margin-left: 5%; background-color: #E8E8E8; border-radius: 20px;">
                <br>
                <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: left;">
                    <?php
                    echo "<a href='anuncio.php?id_usuario=" . $uf_s['id_user'] . "'style='text-decoration: none;'><h4 style='color:black;'> " . $uf_s['nomefantazia'] . "</h4></a>";
                    ?>
                    <p style=" text-align: left; "><b
                                style="color: red;">Categoria: </b><?php echo $uf_s['categoria'] . ''; ?></p>
                    <p style=" text-align: left; "><b
                                style="color: red;">SubCategoria: </b><?php echo $uf_s['subcategoria'] . ''; ?></p>
                    <p style=" text-align: left;"><b
                                style="color: red;">Segmentação: </b> <?php echo $uf_s['segmentacao'] . ''; ?></p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6" style="text-align: left;">
                    <h4 style="color: red;">Dados</h4>
                    <b style="color: red;">Telefone: </b><?php echo $uf_s['telefone'] . ''; ?><br>
                    <b style="color: red;">Cidade: </b><?php echo $uf_s['cidade'] . ''; ?><br>
                    <b style="color: red;">Bairro: </b><?php echo $uf_s['bairro'] . ''; ?><br>
                    <b style="color: red;">Endereço: </b><?php echo $uf_s['endereco'] . ''; ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2" style="margin-top: 1%; color: grey;">
                    <?php
                    if (!isset($uf_s['logo'])) {
                        ?>
                        <img src="assets/img/iconsemfoto.png" style="width: 100%;">
                        <?php
                    } else {
                        ?>
                        <img src="<?php echo substr($uf_s['logo'], 1); ?>" style="width: 100%;">
                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                    <br>
                    <?php
                    echo "<a href='anuncio.php?id_usuario=" . $uf_s['id_user'] . "'style='text-decoration: none;'>"
                    ?>
                    <h5 style="color: red; text-decoration: none;">Saiba Mais...</h5>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <br>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <?php
    }
} else {
    echo '<h4> Informe sua pesquisa no campo acima </h4>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Poste todo o seu código para a pesquisa por favor

Comment: Se são dois campos em sua tabela então você tem que informar dois valores, um valor para categoria e outro valor para cidade. Da maneira como fez você está informando um único valor e utilizando este valor para comparar os dois campos de sua tabela.

Answer (score 0):

Da maneira que esta realizando sua pesquisa esta passando o mesmo valor para as duas coluna, ou seja, nunca vai encontrar a categoria junto com a cidade. Uma solução seria criar uma nova tabela em seu select.

**SQL em MYSQL:**

```
SELECT * 

  FROM 
    (SELECT edicao.campo1, edicao.campo2, edicao.campo3, concat(categoria,' ', cidade) as categoria_cidade FROM edicao) nova_edicao 
 WHERE nova_edicao.categoria_cidade LIKE "%agencias são paulo%"
```

Desta maneira as duas colunas estão unidas e poderá buscar nas duas colunas ao mesmo tempo.

Comment: muito obrigado , porem sou iniciante poderia explicar de uma forma mais fácil agradeço